# dplyr mutate intersect not working

Tags: r, dataframe, intersect, dplyr

I have a sample data frame like this [image] 
I am trying to find the intersection between the 2 columns `coauthors` and `nacoauthors` using the following code

```
interscout = 
  sample_test %>% 
  mutate( commonauth = intersect( coauthors, nacoauthors) )
```

and I get this output [image]
I am not sure why I am not able to get the common intersection set using `intersect` in `mutate`.

Ideally, the last row should be empty and the second row should have only `JAMES M ANDERSON` on intersection.

Here is the code for the structure.

```
> dput(sample_test)
structure(list(fname = c("JACK", "JACK", "JACK"), lname = c("SMITH", 
"SMITH", "SMITH"), cname = c("JACK  SMITH", "JACK A SMITH", "JACK B SMITH"
), coauthors = list(c("AMEY S BAILEY", "JAMES M ANDERSON"), "JAMES M ANDERSON", 
    "JOHN MURRAY"), nacoauthors = list(c("AMEY S BAILEY", "JAMES M ANDERSON"
), c("AMEY S BAILEY", "JAMES M ANDERSON"), c("AMEY S BAILEY", 
"JAMES M ANDERSON"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), vars = list(fname, 
    lname), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:2), group_sizes = 3L, biggest_group_size = 3L, labels = structure(list(
    fname = "JACK", lname = "SMITH"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), vars = list(fname, lname), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("fname", 
"lname")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("fname", "lname", "cname", "coauthors", "nacoauthors"
))
```

Comment: it's going to throw an error because mutate is looking for something of equivalent output length to the full dataset. you could use intersect outside of dply `intersect(sample_test$coauthors, sample_test$nacoauthors)` and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `rowwise()` and make your mutated column a `list` it'll work:

```
interscout <- sample_test %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate( commonauth = list( intersect(coauthors, nacoauthors) ) )
```

FWIW If I don't include `rowwise()` I get `Error: not compatible with STRSXP`

Comment: Thanks! whats the role of ungroup and rowwise here?

Comment: `ungroup()` might not be necessary but its a precaution since your `dput` described a "groupped_df".  If a grouping was in effect for your `data_frame`, `mutate()` would work within that grouping framework instead of comparing each row separately and that's likely not what you'd want here. The `rowwise()` tells `mutate()` to consider each row by itself, which is what you want to make in-row comparisons, like this.